# Не могу вывести на форме данные через WHILE

Tags: php, html, mysql, веб-программирование

Подключаю `require("objects.php");`  - в в этой PHP-ке получаю данные из MYSQL. Данные выводятся корректно в `select`  только вне `body` Внутри тэга  `body` не выводятся.
Как вывести список данных в селект на форме(`name="object"`) ?

```
<?
require("objects.php");

?>

<head>
     <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
     <title> Tex. поддержка </title>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="mainForm">
            <div class="mainContent">       
                <form action="send.php" method="POST" class="actionForm" id="actionForm">
                    <br>
                    <p class="text text-success">Заголовок обращения:</p>
                    <input  type="text" class="caption form-control" name="caption" placeholder="Заголовок обращения" required>
                    <br>
                    <p class="text text-success">Телефон в формате +775291231233</p>
                    <input type="phone" class="phone form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Номер телефона(375291234567)" pattern="[^0-9]{1}[0-9]{11,12}" required>
                    <br>
                    <p class="text text-success"> Тип оборудования</p>
                    <select name="" id="" class="form-control">
                        <option value="" selected></option>
                        <option value="">Кассовое оборудование</option>
                        <option value="">Весовое оборудование</option>
                    </select>
                    <br>



                            <?
                           echo '<select name="object" id="" class="form-control">';
                                 while (($row=$result->fetch_assoc())!= false) {
                                echo '<option value="">'.$row['format'].'</option>';
                            }

                           echo "</select>";
                    ?>


                     <p class="text text-success">Торговый объект</p>
                     <input type="text" class="obj form-control"  name="obj" placeholder="Номер торгового объекта" required>


                    <br>
                    <p class="text text-success">Описание проблемы:</p>
                    <textarea name="text" id="" class="text form-control" cols="30" rows="5" placeholder="Опишите проблему" required></textarea>
                    <br />
                    <button class="btn btn-success"> Отправить</button>
                    <label id="result"></label>
                </form>
            </div>          
        </div>  
</body>
```

Comment: вас не смущает что у вас селект в селекте в коде?

Comment: Ошибся, поправил!

Comment: Обычно нужно все обработки до вывода делать и в `html` отправлять уже готовые данные на вывод.

Comment: если я правильно понял _"вне body"_, то у вас в `objects.php` вывод какой то делает?

Comment: Все верно! Только вне тэга  body выводи как положено информацию. Как в начале страницы так и в конце. Но внутри - нет. Скорее всего не срабатывает само условие. т.е вызывается.

Comment: @ZIBERMINSK "только вне body" - как Вы это выяснили?

Comment: @Igor я пробовал выводить данные вставляя код в разных местах. Только не работал внутри body. Кстати сейчас все работает! Это может происходить из за кэша?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в кэше(op cache ). Данные попадают на форму как надо. Осталась проблема с CSS, но это уже другой вопрос.
Всем спасибо!